# Need help using the random.randint command making a word guessing game

Tags: python

I have been set some homework to make a word guessing game, I have got it to work for the most part but at this point I am using random.choice and that command allows the same string to repeat more than once. I need to know how to use random.randint in this instance.

```
    """ This is a guessing game which allows the person operating the program to
guess what i want for christmas"""
import random
sw = ("Trainers")
print ("In this game you will have 10 chances to guess what I want for christmas, you start with 10 points, each time you guess incorrectly you will be deducted one point. Each time you guess incorrectly you will be given another clue.") 
clue_list = ["They are an item of clothing", "The item comes in pairs", "The Item is worn whilst playing sport", "The item is an inanimate object", "The item can be made of leather","They come in differant sizes", "They have laces", "can be all differant colours", "the item has soles", "Im getting it for christmas ;)"] 

def guessing_game(sw, clue_list):
    x = 10
    while x<=10 and x > 0:
        answer = input("What do I want for christmas?")
        if sw.lower() == answer and answer.isalpha():
            print ("Good Guess thats what I want for christmas")
            print ("You scored %s points" % (x))
            break

        else:
            print ("incorrect, " + random.choice(clue_list))
            x -=1
    if x == 0:
        print ("You lost, try again")

guessing_game(sw, clue_list)
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

`randint()` is very straightforward. If you want to know how to refer to elements in your list, you can do: `clue_list[0]` to get the first item, `clue_list[1]` to get the second, and so on.

If you do it that way, you could save a list of which entries in your `clue_list` you have already displayed, and then make sure that the new clues are not in that list. Hope that helps.

Comment: Seriously, why didn't you read the docs first? Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380)

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ: No need to be mean. His/her problem isn't "how do I use `randint`", his/her problem is actually "how do I keep from displaying my choices more than once." Not a good fit, I know, but reading the docs isn't helpful to a beginner.

Comment: @Symmitchry Good point about his/her question, but the serious lack of research effort remains. If he/she wrote that code, then I'd say that he/she is ready to read the docs :p It's true that the docs won't solve the immediate problem, but patience will. And OP: I'm actually helping you to learn, it just doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I think reading the docs is *very* helpful to a beginner, or at least to someone who grasps the most basic elements of syntax.  The problem that many beginners have is in figuring out where to start.  Reading documentation reinforces that you start at the *beginning* (more elaboratively, starting at the beginning means you start by understanding all the steps of what your code does, which is what documentation tells you).

Comment: I would [shuffle](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the list and [pop](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=pop#mutable-sequence-types) the elements.

Comment: @Matthias Me too :p thanks for reminding me. +1

Answer (score 0):

for your implementation I think you want:

```
clueint = random.randint(0, len(clue_list))
print("incorrect, " + clue_list[clueint])
```

to ensure the same clues are not displayed twice declare an empty list to store guess in OUTSIDE the function definition:

```
clues_shown = []
```

and then add each `int` to the list:

```
def showClue():
    clueint = random.randint(0, len(clue_list))
    if clueint in clues_shown:
        showClue()
    else: 
        clues_shown.append(clueint)
        print("incorrect, " + clue_list[clueint])
```

Comment: I think the recursive calls to `show_clue()` are too confusing for a total beginner. I would suggest popping clues out of the first list (`list.pop([i])`), or just check that `shown_clues < clue_list`.

Comment: @Symmitchry thats a fair point actually... easy to forget what confused you as a beginner, I was deeply confused about recursion for a good while. Still, no sign of the OP since the post so I will leave it as is for now.

Comment: Just seen this, thanks for the help guys, am going to test it now